# Como chamar um outro arquivo html no ionic?

Tags: html, ionic

Bom dia, eu estou tentando chamar um arquivo html a partir de outro html que criei pelo ionic, porem ele simplesmente não chama.

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <a class="button button-clear  icon-right ion-chevron-right a href="tab-servicos-categorias.html""><font size="2">Categoria </font></a>
</label>
```

Outra questão tbm, eu criei este botão por esse código acima tbm, mas o ícone `">"` fica perto do texto "**Categoria**" quando na verdade eu quero que ele fique no fim do botão.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, você quer navegar entre views:

1) defina suas rotas ([veja este exemplo](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/))

2) defina seus controllers

3) use `ui-sref=` ao invés de `href=`